# Debugging AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, http, afnetworking

The following chunk of code is used to submit an image file to a database. It has stopped working: Even though it prints `SUCCESS`, there are no images visible on the server. Any advice as to how to debug this?

**EDITS**

I printed the imageData in the debugger and got an array of memory address, so I am almost sure I have an image.

```
- (void)postActivityImage:(Spot*)localSpot
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__func__);
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v1/activity/%@/image", localSpot.uniqueID];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:localSpot.imageLocalURL];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5f);
    NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient_ multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                   path:url 
                                                             parameters:nil 
                                              constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                                                  [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData 
                                                                              name:@"test" 
                                                                          fileName:@"test" 
                                                                          mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                                              }];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *ro;
    ro = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                                             NSLog(@"success: %@", JSON);
                                                             NSLog(@"SUCCESS - IMAGE POSTED.");
                                                             [self updateSpotSubmitInProgressStatusWithActivityFinished:ImagePost andSuccess:YES];
                                                             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SUBMIT_STATUS object:self userInfo:nil];
                                                             self.spot.imageSubmitted = YES;
                                                         } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                             [self updateSpotSubmitInProgressStatusWithActivityFinished:ImagePost andSuccess:NO];
                                                             NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:error, @"Error", nil];
                                                             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SUBMIT_STATUS object:self userInfo:dic];
                                                             NSLog(@"%s   ERROR: %@", __func__, error);
                                                             NSLog(@"%s   RESPONSE: %@",__func__, response);
                                                             NSLog(@"%s   FAIL   json response: %@",__func__, JSON);
                                                         }];

    [httpClient_ enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:ro];
}
```

Comment: You said "it has stopped working." Was it working previously with no changes?

Comment: you might also want to check the image locally, making sure its afnetworking and not the image itself.  you could easily set the image object to a uiimageview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My go-to tool when debugging HTTP connections is [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). You can set up Charles on your desktop computer, configure it as a proxy on your iPhone and then watch the HTTP traffic that your iPhone produces. You can then see if the requests are even being made and, if so, examine each request in depth.

Here are some good instructions for setting up Charles to view iPhone HTTP traffic: http://blog.mediarain.com/2009/08/iphone-http-connection-debugging/